# Расширить контроллер

Tags: php, yii

```
public function actions(){
  return array(
    'hello'=>'application.components.actions.Hello',
  );
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно-ли в Hello добавить `actionCreate`, например? Т.е чтобы получилось site/hello/create.

Или нужно что-то по другому сделать?

Comment: можно сделать Site модулем, Hello контроллером, Create action. 

еще можно настроить роуты, например как для REST.

Comment: Думаю, да! Модулем самое то. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

нет. но можно добавить экшен createHello и с помощью роутов создать урл site/hello/create

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно только придется долго плясать с классом CBaseurlRule